# JSOUP txt parse as HTML parses incorrectly when there is alphabet character immediately after a less than symbol (<)

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I have a text with an alphabet character or a word immediately after a less than symbol (eg: <one) to parse as a html. I have used JSOUP for parsing and it does not gives the result as expected. Here is my sample code.

```java
String source = "&lt;span style=\"font-size: small;\"&gt;Â &lt;one kg &lt;/span&gt;" ;
String html = htmlUnescape(source); //this is SpringFrameworks HtmlUtils.htmlUnscape
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
doc.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html);
String parsedHTML = doc.body().toString();
        
System.out.println(parsedHTML);
```

And the result is

```
<body>  <span style="font-size: small;">Â&nbsp;   <one kg <span></one></span> </body>
```

This is totally wrong. '<One' got identified as a Tag opening. What I want is

```
<span style="font-size: small;">Â&nbsp;&lt;one&nbsp;kg&nbsp;</span>
```

However it works correctly if the source string does not have an alphabet character immediately after a less than symbol. As an example
if the source String is

```
&lt;span style="font-size: small;"&gt;Â &lt; one kg &lt;/span&gt;
```

then the result is

```
<span style="font-size: small;">Â&nbsp;&lt; one kg </span>
```

and it is correct.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue. JSOUP version I'm using is 'jsoup-1.13.1'.
Anyways I'm open to any library as long as it is java.

Comment: This seems like correct behavior to me.  Why *wouldn’t* a parser assume that `<` followed by a tag name is a tag?  The real problem is that your HTML is malformed.  A `<` which is not meant to form an opening tag or comment or DTD is required to be escaped.  Correct HTML would look like: `<span style="font-size: small;">Â&nbsp;&lt;one kg <span>`  (By the way, `Â&nbsp;` is almost certainly the result of erroneously reading the document using an ISO 8859-x or windows-125x charset instead of UTF-8.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will check the charset issue. However for the HTML, As I have shown in the description I did an un-escaping before parsing the string. After the the un-escaping, the intermediate value is   `<span style="font-size: small;">Â <one kg </span>`. So this is the value JSOUP actually uses for parsing. Is this also wrong?  What do I need to do to make it correct.

Comment: Aside from the charset, you haven’t done anything wrong.  The problem is that the HTML itself is broken.  `<one` is not allowed in an HTML document (unless it was intended to start an HTML element, which seems unlikely).  You may have to resort to drastic measures, like manually replacing any occurrence of `&lt;one` with `&amp;lt;one` in the input.